# Rewriting image output in views: how to provide replacement pattern inside twig tag?

Tags: views, 8, theming

In views I want to rewrite output of image field by using twig function `drupal_image` (see module [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak)). When I provide the image path directly, this code works:

```
{{ drupal_image('public://myimage.jpg' , image_responsive_style, responsive=true) }}
```

But I can not manage to provide image path by a variable, like this pseudocode:

```
{{ drupal_image('{{ uri }}' , image_responsive_style, responsive=true) }}
```

The problem seems to be how to provide the variable `{{ uri }}` properly inside the surrounding twig tag.

Comment: Remove the quotes arounded; otherwise, you are litteraly passing it as a string rather than a variable.

Comment: Removing the quotes doesn't work neither.

Comment: also forgot to mention remove the wiggly brackets around uri, `{{ drupal_image(uri, image_responsive_style, responsive=true) }}`

Comment: What variable is `uri`? In an image field there is no such variable. You could use `field_image__target_id` though, because the twig function also works with a file id.

Comment: @NoSssweat: Your code in the above comments worked, and you were the first one who answered, but another user was the first who made an answer of it – so how should I vote?

Comment: Accept their answer, it's all good :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Remove quotes.
2. Remove wiggly brackets around.
3. Surround `image_responsive_style` by quote.
4. `responsive=true` Should passed as object:

```
    {{ drupal_image(uri , 'image_responsive_style', {responsive: true}) }}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about point 4. Twig seems to support named parameters. Otherwise this example from the cheat sheet of Twig Tweak: `{{ drupal_image('public://ocean.jpg', 'wide', responsive=true) }}` wouldn't work, because `responsive` is a boolean in fourth position.

Comment: yes i agree, you can pass `responsive=true` as boolean in the fourth position or as an attribute in the third, i have tested both but the first one doesn't work `{{ drupal_image(uri , 'medium', {}, responsive=true) }}` this doesn't work for me.